# Square matrix and determinant inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A, B, C$ be invertible $n \times n$ square matrices with $AC=CA$ and $B^2C^2=I_n$
Is $\det(ABC +CBA +A^2+I_n)$  always $\geq 0$?

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you have any reason to believe this?

Comment: Yes, it's from a problem and this relation needs to be satisfied so that my proof stands. I'm not 100% sure it's true, but I guess so.

Answer (score 3):

It's true if all the matrices are real. From $BBCC=I$, we get $CBBC=I$. Therefore
$$\det(ABC+CBA+A^2+I)=\det\left((A+CB)(A+BC)\right).\tag{1}$$
As $A$ commutes with $C$, it also commutes with $C^{-1}$. Therefore
$$\det(A+CB)=\det(C)\det(C^{-1}A+B)=\det(AC^{-1}+B)\det(C)=\det(A+BC).$$
Hence the RHS of $(1)$ is equal to $\det(A+BC)^2$, which is nonnegative when $A,B,C$ are real.